# if($v) объясните какое значение идет в массив

Tags: php

```
if($v) объясните какое значение идет в массив
Perl вот ключ например , а какое значение у него

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <title>Гарантированный прием значений от флажков</title>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
</head>
<body>
  <?php
  if (isset($_REQUEST['doGo'])) {
    foreach ($_REQUEST['known'] as $k => $v) {
      if($v) echo "Вы знаете язык $k!<br>";
      else echo "Вы не знаете языка $k. <br>";
    }
  }
  ?>
  <form action="<?=$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']?>" method="post">
    Какие языки программирования вы знаете?<br />
    <input type="hidden" name="known[PHP]" value="0">
    <input type="checkbox" name="known[PHP]" value="1">PHP<br />

    <input type="hidden" name="known[Perl]" value="0">
    <input type="checkbox" name="known[Perl]" value="1">Perl<br />

    <input type="submit" name="doGo" value="Go!">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Кто плюсует-то? Человек ни единой попытки разобраться не сделал.

Answer (score 0):

Идет то значение какое Вы выбрали. Если Вы нажали checkbox то значение у элемента массива с ключем перл будет 1, если не нажали то 0. В html же всё написано теги инпут с аттрибутами hidden с значением 0, а чекбоксы с 1.